# Flutter Table layout is not responding according to expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Using Flutter v1.20.2**

The following code

```dart
var data = [
  ['a', 'VerylongstringwithnospacesVerylongstringwithnospaces'],
  ['abc', '123456789'],
  ['abcdefg', '123'],
];


Expanded(
  child: Table(
    border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.red),
    columnWidths: {
      0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
      1: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
    },
    children: data.map<TableRow>((x) => (
      TableRow(
        children: <TableCell>[
          TableCell(child: Container(child: Text(x[0]))),
          TableCell(child: Container(color: Colors.green, child: Text(x[1]))),
        ],
      )
    )).toList(),
  ),
),
```

results in this layout

[image]

As you can see the text overflows the boundary of the table.

I have tried innumerable solutions but none have worked. It appears that the TableCell itself has a width bigger than it should have, comparing to the size of the column of the table.

The biggest problem is that the size of both columns are unknown, they could be hundreds of characters long or single letter. In case of it being bigger than the width the text should break to the next line.

Is there a way to make a fluid grid layout so that both sides resize according to the amount of content for each Column? The ideal layout would be something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why It’s happening is that the `IntrinsicColumnWidth` doesn’t give `TableCell` parent size. Because it's trying to set the column width based on child width. At the same time, to make text wrapping on lines, you need to have the width of parent, otherwise text widget don’t know it’s limits.

What options do you have :

- `FixedColumnWidth`
- `FlexColumnWidth`
- `FractionColumnWidth`
- `MaxColumnWidth`
- `MinColumnWidth`

(Last two widgets used max/min of other `TableColumnWidth` widgets.)

In your case if you know that the text in the first column never will need to be wraped in lines, you can remove IntrinsicColumnWidth as parameter of second column. If you know that long text is possible, add the maximum width by adding `MinColumnWidth`

[dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/3560f68668fec6273ee957ad3a84878c)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me discover what the problem was, I ended up going for a different approach, by calculating the min/max length for each string and setting a fractionWidth as you mentioned.